# Ruby on Rail by M.Hartl, Chapter 10/11(activation/password reset) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm a newbie to RoR and am following Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Sample App tutorial. Whist completing chapter 10 and 11 have come across and issue I am unsure how to solve.

All my test pass fine but when using the app live through Heroku.com, the app will send the automated activation and password reset emails however when the user clicks on the link in these emails the web browser is directed to an 'untitled:blank' page.

Does anyone know how I can solve this. Please see some of the related code below and let me know if you need to see anymore.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks (In advance)

Faye Matthews

routes.rb =

```
1 Rails.application.routes.draw do
2   root 'static_pages#home'
3   get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
4   get '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
5   get '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
6   get '/signup', to: 'users#new'
7   get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
8   post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
9   delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
10   resources :users
11   resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
12   resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
13 end
```

user_mailer/password_reset.html.erb =

```
1 <h1>Password reset</h1>
2 <p>To reset you password click the link below:</p>
3
4 <%= link_to "Reset password",  edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
5                                                        email: @user.email) %>
6
7 <p> This link will expire in two hours.</p>
8
9 <p>
10 If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.
11 </p>
```

user_mailer/password_reset.text.erb =

```
1 To reset you password click the link below:
2
3 <%= edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %>
4
5 This link will expire in two hours.
6
7 If you did not request you password to be reset, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.
```

environments/production.rb =

```
60   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
61   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
62   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => '<safe-falls-22225>.herokuapp.com' }
63   ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
64     :address                => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
65     :port                   => '587',
66     :authentication         => :plain,
67       :user_name            => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
68       :password             => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
69       :domain               => 'heroku.com',
70       :enable_starttls_auto => true
71   }
```

Comment: is this <safe-falls-22225> the name of your herokuapp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `line:62` in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'safe-falls-22225.herokuapp.com' }
```

you have a typo in your `default_url_options`